# Trouble optimizing some code

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to right a function with three.js. every thing is working as intended but the FPS considerably drops after like 20-30 seconds of running the function. The function is set up to move a sprite then destroy the sprite after it reaches it's destination. Then it spawns a new sprite at a random location. Before moving the sprite it's moving at about 30 FPS. When I start moving the sprite the FPS drops to low 20's. After about 20 to 30 seconds it's at about 9. If I stop moving the sprite the FPS is back up at 30. But if I try to move the sprite again instead of repeating the earlier process it just goes right back to about 9. Now I know that javascript is a garbage collected langue so I figured it just needs some time to clean things up. But even if I let it sit for 10 minutes it still just goes right back down to 9 FPS. On the other had if I reload the page the process starts all over. I also tried just moving the sprite instead of destroying it and respawing but I get the same issue. Also I tried to use the .dispose method but had no luck. Here's the code.

```
  function spriteAI1() {
        //console.log(c2Sprite.position.x);
        //console.log(ranLocX);
        //console.log(ranTen);
        console.log(c2Sprite.position);
        //var ranTen = Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+2);
            if (c2Sprite.position.x > 30 && c2Sprite.position.x <= 450) { 
            //var ranTen = Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1);
            c2Sprite.translateX( -6 );
            } else if (c2Sprite.position.y > 30 && c2Sprite.position.y <= 250) {
            //var ranTen = Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1);
            c2Sprite.translateY( -6 );
            } else if (c2Sprite.position.z > 30 && c2Sprite.position.z <= 350) {
            //var ranTen = Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1);
            c2Sprite.translateZ( -6 );
            } else if (c2Sprite.position.x < -30 && c2Sprite.position.x >= -450) {
            //var ranTen = Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1);
            c2Sprite.translateX( 6 );
            } else if (c2Sprite.position.y < -30 && c2Sprite.position.y >= -250) {
            //var ranTen = Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1);
            c2Sprite.translateY( 6 );
            } else if (c2Sprite.position.z < -30 && c2Sprite.position.z >= -350) {
            //var ranTen = Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1);
            c2Sprite.translateZ( 6 );
            } else if (c2Sprite.position.x < 31 && c2Sprite.position.y < 31 && c2Sprite.position.z < 31 && c2Sprite.position.x > -31 && c2Sprite.position.y > -31 && c2Sprite.position.z > -31) { 
            var locX = Math.floor((Math.random()*450)+1);
            locX *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;
            var locY = Math.floor((Math.random()*250)+1);
            locY *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;
            var locZ = Math.floor((Math.random()*350)+1);
            locZ *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;
            //c2Sprite.delete;
            scene.remove(c2Sprite);
            //console.log("AI1");
            //geometry.dispose();
            //material.dispose();
            //texture.dispose();
            c2ImgMaterial.dispose();
            c2Sprite.position.set( locX, locY, locZ );
            scene.add( c2Sprite );
            //c2Sprite.clone;
            }
        }
```

Comment: How often are you calling this function? What is the surrounding code? Have you inspected your frames with dev tools?

Comment: The function is being called constantly when testing. The surrounding code just creates a three.js scene and user controls. I have not used any developer tool. I'm very new to programming. It's just strange that the performance drops so much and the only way to fix it is to reload. I used the task manager to check how much memory is being used. It goes up when the function is running but then returns back to normal about 10 seconds after it stops. So I don't thing it's a memory leak. To me it seems like every time I remove the sprite and add a new one it's just making the first one invisible.

Comment: That is a memory leak. The memory shouldn't be constantly increasing during your run loop if you want constant fps. Also, it would help to see the surrounding code

Comment: @Wyatt I figured it out. It was a real noob mistake. I was using console.log to check the value of position.x position.y and position.z and over time the log was getting so big that it was affecting my FPS that's why I had to reload the page to fix the issue. Sorry for wasting your time.